# Domain Routing using A Records + CNAME Records + 301 redirects in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, dns, cname, a-records

Let's say I have a domain that people want to read both as a root and 'www':

```
example.com
www.example.com
```

The way I could go about this is to make these A records

```
@ A 127.0.0.1
www A 127.0.0.1
```

Now lets say, I wanted to forward all 'www' traffic to the root. I would use mod_rewrite and .htaccess to put a 301 redirect in from the root level domain over to the 'www' variant - like this:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(.*)\.example\.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Finally, lets say I wanted to forward all root traffic to 'www'. I would use mod_rewrite and .htaccess to put a 301 redirect in from 'www' over to the root level domain - like this:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

My real question is this: should I be using CNAMEs here somewhere? Technically, I could push 'www' over to the root with a CNAME (I think), like this:

```
www CNAME example.com
```

Is that valid/desirable? What's best practice here? A Records + 301 or A Records + CNAMEs?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it either way in DNS, the effect is the same.  (Of course, using 127.0.0.1 in your example is a bit ridiculous.)

Comment: Yeah, IP and domains and bunk intentionally ;) Thanks for the feedback, wonder what others think here...